# Metric for end to end processing time

Tags: traefik, traefik-ingress

We are using traefik as an ingress controller in our k8s cluster, and want to define a metric for end to end processing time for one of the service (Service A).

What we want as end to end processing time is time taken from request initiated by client to time taken to deliver the response to client.

For this we tried to use `traefik_entrypoint_request_duration_seconds_bucket` but we noticed that the time shown using this is very less compared to the actual time.

Example: this metric shows 8 ms as the end to end time, whereas using curl to hit our service, we see a processing time of 80 ms. Is there a way to calculate this end to end time by using traefik?